# How to update DOM during a async call

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a async function as below

```
async function predict_from_model() {
  $("#loading").html("first update")
  const model = await tf.loadModel('model.json');
  $("#loading").html("second update") //doesn't happen
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     const model = await tf.loadModel('model.json');
     $("#loading").html("more updates") //doesn't happen
  }
  ...
  <more code>
  ...
}
```

the second and third update don't happen until after the entire code block is completed. I saw online that it would be possible to fix this by wrapping the function in a `setTimeout`, however this doesn't work for me either:

```
async function predict_from_model() {
  $("#loading").html("first update")
  const model = await tf.loadModel('model.json');
  setTimeout(function() {
      $("#loading").html("loaded") //doesn't happen
  }, 0);
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     const model = await tf.loadModel('model.json');
     $("#loading").html("more updates") //doesn't happen
  }
  ...
  ...
  <more code>
  ...
}
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: doesn't the very fact that you are using `async-await`, mean that you want to **wait** till `tf.loadModel` call is done? Not able to understand what is the ultimate goal here. If you want to make that call asynchronous and do not want to wait for it to complete, just remove `await` from there

Comment: @kiddorails Yes, I do want to wait for it to be completed. However, immediately after it completes, I want the next line of code (the one that updates the DOM) to happen. This isn't what happens, the DOM only updates at the end of the function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/92xgmLdj/ I wrote a quick (and dirty) js using async-await, where i'm also updating dom after each await. It is working correctly for me. If this works for you too, we will need to brainstorm on more details of your code.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it working. If you post your answer with the jsfiddle I will accept it.

Comment: sure. posted that as answer. however, why wasn't it working for you, if i may ask?

Comment: It was one of the calls to tensorflow.js that was causing issues. Entirely my fault for asking the question in the first place, but I couldn't find any other stackoverflow questions dealing with await calls so I wrongly assumed that was the issue. Your answer provided the necessary clarity to me though, so thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery dom manipulation shouldn't be stalled for function to get over. Here is a quick (and dirty) snippet which shows that:

```js
var hardWork = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(_ => { 
      console.log("hardwork over")
      resolve();
    }, 2000)
  })
}

async function dom() {
  $("#loading").html('Loading')
  $('#status').html('Loading at ' + new Date())
  
  await hardWork();
  $('#status').html('Loading at ' + new Date())
  $("#loading").html('Loading 2')
  
  await hardWork();
  $('#status').html('Loading again at ' + new Date())
  $("#loading").html('Loading 3')

}
dom();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="status">

</p>
<p id="loading">

</p>
```