# Update the UI with html that is added to a div during foreach iteration

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

We are trying to add some elements to a div using the `Ajax` call. The div is basically a template which is used to add multiple items of the template type to a parent div.

Since the data returned from the server could be huge, so what we want is that while the Ajax call is adding templates to the div, they should immediately appear on the page so that progress is visible to the user. right now, the updated html is displayed only once the `OnSuccess` method executes. Since I am adding the company-card to the card-list int he foreach loop, so I expect the UI to be updated during each iteration. am i wrong? if so, how to fix this?

Here is the `html` of the template.

```
    <div class='row card-list'>
        @*All Companies will be added here dynamically using AJAX call.*@
    </div>

    <template id="company-card">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mb-30">
            <div class="w3-card-4 w3-hover-shadow ">
                <img src="" class="companylogo" alt="Alps" style="height:133px; width:350px; padding: 10px;border-bottom:1px solid #efebeb;" />
                <div class="w3-container w3-center">
                    <h5 class="CompanyName" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">
                        <span class="badge EstablishDate" style="font-size: 10px;float: right;"></span>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="custom-labels" style="position:relative;">
                        <h6 style="color: #777;">Country:  <span class="Country" style="color:#C1A16B;font-weight:bold;"></span></h6>
                        <h6 style="color: #777;position: absolute;right: 0;top: -7px;">Score&nbsp;<span class="label label-default CompanyScore"></span></h6>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="CompanyDescription"></h5>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

and here the Ajax method which is displaying the card-list from data that is returned from server.

```
$('#btnLoadMore').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.card-list').html("");
        var isLocal = @((HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal).ToString().ToLower());
         var basePath = "";
         if (isLocal == false)
            basePath = "/roadshow";
        $('.showLoader').css('display', 'block !important');
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: basePath + "/Companies/GetCompanies/",
            data: { countryFilter: $('#CountryFilter').val(), companyFilter: $('#CompanyFilter').val() },
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (response) {

                response.companies.FilterResult.forEach(function (ele) {
                    let card = $($('#company-card').html());
                    card.find('.companylogo').attr('src', ele.CompanyLogo);
                    card.find('.CompanyName').text(ele.CompanyName);
                    card.find('.EstablishDate').text(ele.EstablishDate);
                    card.find('.Country').text(ele.Country);
                    card.find('.CompanyScore').text(ele.CompanyScore);
                    card.find('.CompanyDescription').text(ele.CompanyDescription);
                    $('.card-list').append(card);
                });
            },
        });
        $('.showLoader').css('display', 'none');
    });
```

Comment: $('.card-list').append(card) - does this not update the ui as it gets executed?

Comment: @Vince nope.. the UI gets updated only after the `onsuccess` function finishes executing. which is strange for me. i was also expecting the UI to update after the `append`. any pointers?

Comment: I would probably use promises, or even promise chaining it the data is too much - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899469/how-to-update-dom-during-a-async-call

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetInterval if you want to append values when you have results after response, I don't know how is your response structure but you will get an idea.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: basePath + "/Companies/GetCompanies/",
    data: { countryFilter: $('#CountryFilter').val(), companyFilter: $('#CompanyFilter').val() },
    datatype: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (response) {
        iteration = 0;
        data = response
        myinterval = setInterval(funciton(){
            iteration++
            ele = data[iteration]
            let card = $($('#company-card').html());
            card.find('.companylogo').attr('src', ele.CompanyLogo);
            card.find('.CompanyName').text(ele.CompanyName);
            card.find('.EstablishDate').text(ele.EstablishDate);
            card.find('.Country').text(ele.Country);
            card.find('.CompanyScore').text(ele.CompanyScore);
            card.find('.CompanyDescription').text(ele.CompanyDescription);
            $('.card-list').append(card);

            if(iteration == data.length){
                clearInterval(myinterval)
            }
        }, 1000)


        response.companies.FilterResult.forEach(function (ele) {

        });
    },
});
```